# What is the name of this mountain range in Colorado?

Tags: usa, identify-this, colorado

In [Larkspur](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Larkspur,_Colorado), Colorado there is a place (beginning of the arrow in the map below) from which you can see a mountain range.

[image: Map]

[Google Maps](https://www.google.com/maps/@39.2400522,-104.9561333,211m/data=!3m1!1e3)

This is that mountain range looks like:

[image: View of the mountain range]

[Street view](https://www.google.com/maps/@39.2400522,-104.9561333,3a,75y,212.02h,89.62t/data=!3m7!1e1!3m5!1s17f5AwktJGHkmoRplvw5fg!2e0!6s%2F%2Fgeo0.ggpht.com%2Fcbk%3Fpanoid%3D17f5AwktJGHkmoRplvw5fg%26output%3Dthumbnail%26cb_client%3Dmaps_sv.tactile.gps%26thumb%3D2%26w%3D203%26h%3D100%26yaw%3D139.41212%26pitch%3D0%26thumbfov%3D100!7i16384!8i8192)

What are the names of this mountain range or some of the mountains visible there?

Comment: West Plum Creek?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rampart_Range

Comment: @BernhardDöbler If you submit your comment as an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had no idea, so I did a bit of googling. I suggest, these mountains belong to the [Rampart Range](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rampart_Range)

Comment: Yep.  You can see it labeled "Rampart Range" on USGS topo maps, for instance.